# Evolutionary Algorithm is not improving

Tags: python, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm, fitness

Over the weekend I tried building a Neural Network, which improves using an evolutionary algorithm. I ran it for 5000 generations in the Cartpole environment of openai (https://www.openai.com/) but it doesn't improve really well. The Neural Network has 4 Inputs, 1 Hidden Layer with 3 Units, 1 Output and the Network uses tanH as activation function. Every generation has 100 individuals, 5 of them are chosen to form the next generation, with a 20% chance of mutation. Here's the Code for better understanding:

```
import operator
import gym
import math
import random
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')

generations = 100
input_units = 4
Hidden_units = 3
output_units = 1
individuals = 100

fitest1 = []
fitest2 = []

def Neural_Network(x, weights1, weights2):
    global output
    output = list(map(operator.mul, x, weights1))
    output = numpy.tanh(output)
    output = list(map(operator.mul, output, weights2))
    output = sum(output)
    return(output)

weights1 = [[random.random() for i in range(input_units*Hidden_units)] for j in range(individuals)]
weights2 = [[random.random() for i in range(Hidden_units*output_units)] for j in range(individuals)]

fit_plot = []

for g in range(generations):
    print('generation:',g+1)
    fitness=[0 for f in range(individuals)]
    prev_obs = []
    observation = env.reset()
    for w in weights1:
        print('        individual ',weights1.index(w)+1, ' of ', len(weights1))
        env.reset()
        for t in range(500):
            #env.render()
            Neural_Network(observation, weights1[weights1.index(w)], weights2[weights1.index(w)])
            action = output < 0.5
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            fitness[weights1.index(w)]+=reward
            if done:
                break
        print('        individual fitness:', fitness[weights1.index(w)])
    print('min fitness:', min(fitness))
    print('max fitness:', max(fitness))
    print('average fitness:', sum(fitness)/len(fitness))
    fit_plot.append(sum(fitness)/len(fitness))
    for f in range(10):
        fitest1.append(weights1[fitness.index(max(fitness))])
        fitest2.append(weights2[fitness.index(max(fitness))])
        fitness[fitness.index(max(fitness))] = -1000000000


    for x in range(len(weights1)):
        for y in range(len(weights1[x])):
            weights1[x][y]=random.choice(fitest1)[y]
            if random.randint(1,5) == 1:
                weights1[random.randint(0, len(weights1)-1)][random.randint(0, len(weights1[0])-1)] += random.choice([0.1, -0.1])

    for x in range(len(weights2)):
        for y in range(len(weights2[x])):
            weights2[x][y]=random.choice(fitest2)[y]
            if random.randint(1,5) == 1:
                weights1[random.randint(0, len(weights1)-1)][random.randint(0, len(weights1[0])-1)] += random.choice([0.1, -0.1])

plt.axis([0,generations,0,100])
plt.ylabel('fitness')
plt.xlabel('generations')
plt.plot(range(0,generations), fit_plot)
plt.show()

env.reset()
for t in range(100):
    env.render()
    Neural_Network(observation, fitest1[0], fitest2[0])
    action = output < 0.5
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done:
        break
```

And if anyone wonders, a graph of the average fitness over the generations (I only ran it for 100 generations this time)[image: As you can see, the algorithm is not improving]

If there are still any Questions, just ask.

Comment: how do you chose the individuals? How do you do you get the weights of the off spring?

Comment: look at line 53 to 69.

Comment: If you want to verify your code, perhaps have a look at the [NeuralFit](https://neuralfit.net/) library. It also has a [cartpole example](https://neuralfit.net/examples/cart-pole/). You could compare it to your evaluation function.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that in evolutionary algorithm you are not choosing correct individuals at the end of EA. Ensure that you are choosing the best 2 individuals(could work with only one but we want to be better than that :) ) for new generation. This should improve a desired result :)

Answer (score 0):

The chance of mutation seems very high with 20%. Try lowering it to 1-5%, that usually yielded better results from my experiments so far.